# How to set classpath when I use javax.tools.JavaCompiler compile the source?

Tags: java, java-6, java-compiler-api, jsr199

I use the class `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` (jdk6) to compile a source file, but the source file depends on some jar file. How to set the classpath of the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [javax.tools.JavaCompiler#getTask()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) method takes an `options` parameter that allows to set compiler options. The following [message](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10377161#10377161) describes an easy way to set them in order to access the calling program's classpath:

> You need to configure the standard
>   java file manager to know about the
>   jar files(s) - you use the compiler
>   options argument to do that.
>
> By default the java compiler object
>   only seems to know about the default
>   locations for bootclasspath, extdirs
>   and endorseddirs directories in terms
>   of its classpath.
>
> **You need to add the calling program's
>   current classpath to the java compiler
>   instance's which gets passed on the
>   the standard file manager, which will
>   then find classes in the jar files.**
>
> Here's how I do it in [the compiler
>   wrapper I wrote](https://hickory.dev.java.net/source/browse/hickory/trunk/code/src/net/java/dev/hickory/testing/Compilation.java?rev=11&view=markup)
>
> ```
> List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
> // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
> optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath",System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
>
> // any other options you want
> optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList(options));
>
> JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(out,jfm,diagnostics,optionList,null,jfos);
> ```

All you'll need then is to get the proper classpath set when running the calling program.

Comment: Satheesh posted this as an answer, "Would you be able to share your compiler wrapper( link does not work) thanks in advance."

Comment: thanks a mill for this post, ive been struggling with this for ages and this was the answer... cheers :)

Comment: BTW, `classpath` option of `JavaCompiler` doesn't "understand" wildcards. So each `jar` you have to add directly in this string.

Comment: The solution provided in [this blog post](http://atamur.blogspot.de/2009/10/using-built-in-javacompiler-with-custom.html) helped me a lot. It doesn't work with setting the classpath via an option property. It implements a custom file manager to load classes from an existing classloader (e.g. a web application classloader).

Comment: This also helped me a lot.  I'm setting up a complicated JUnit in my Maven project, where I'm creating .java files on the fly.  Wanted a way to inherit the current classpath, and then add a bit.  The answer is obvious really ;), but I wasn't sure it'd work inside Maven, inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

The same problem occurred to me recently, finally I found two workarounds. You can set the class path either by invoke `StandardJavaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, "YOUR_CLASS_PATH")` or `Compiler.getTask(ARG_0, ARG_1, ARG_2, CLASS_PATH_OPTIONS,`  just as the first answer posted here says.

Comment: To get this to work I needed to do `StandardJavaFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, Arrays.asList(new File(classpath)));`

Answer (score 0):

I needed something simpler than the examples above.

The following is a self-contained example of using the built-in Java compiler, and setting the classpath for the compiler to use.

It is equivalent to creating a source file called HelloPrinter.java and then compiling it as follows:

```
javac -classpath C:\Users\dab\Testing\a.jar;c:\path\etc org\abc\another\HelloPrinter.java
```

Note how the classpath can be set using a String[] of options. This should be familiar if you're already used to running javac on the command line (as above).

This code is compatible with Java 6. You will need a JDK, not a JRE, for this to run. This example doesn't actually use the classpath. It all does is print "Hello". You can add an ***import*** statement to the generated source and call a method in an external Jar file to test this properly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JavaCompilerExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String className = "HelloPrinter";
        String directoryName = "org/abc/another";
        new File(directoryName).mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directoryName+"/"+className+".java");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        ps.println(
                "package "+directoryName.replace("/", ".")  + " ; "
                + "public class " +className + 
                "{ public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(\"Hello\");} }");
        ps.close();
        
        JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        String javacOpts[] = {"-classpath", 
                             "C:\\Users\\dab\\Testing\\a.jar;c:\\path\\etc;",
                              directoryName+"/"+className + ".java"};
        
        if ( javac.run(null, null, null,  javacOpts)!=0 ) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        
    }

}
```