# Java compiler API ClassLoader

Tags: java, compiler-construction, classloader

I am trying to use Java Compiler API to compile some java class. That class imports some packages from the jar files which can be loaded by context ClassLoader, let's call him X, which is NOT the system classloader. When I run the compilation, the compiler complains about not recognizing the imports. I have tried to specify the fileManager to pass the classloader, but it does not help.

When compile method is called, it first prints "CLASS LOADED", so the context ClassLoader CAN find the dependency class. However, the compilation itself fails (I get "Compilation FAILED" message) and during the compilation I get errors like this:

/path/to/my/Source.java:3: package my.dependency does not exist
import my.dependency.MyClass;
^

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way to pass custom classloader to the compilationTask? I can't extract the URLs from the ClassLoader since it's not URLClassLoader.

My methods are here:

```
public void compile(List<File> filesToCompile) {
       JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

       StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager =
               compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
       Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = stdFileManager
               .getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(filesToCompile);

       FileManagerImpl fileManager = new FileManagerImpl(stdFileManager);

       CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, fileObjects);
       Boolean result = task.call();
       if (result == true) {
           System.out.println("Compilation has succeeded");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Compilation FAILED");
       }
}

private final class FileManagerImpl extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager> {

      public FileManagerImpl(JavaFileManager fileManager) {
           super(fileManager);
      }

      @Override
      public ClassLoader getClassLoader(JavaFileManager.Location location) {
          ClassLoader def = getContextClassLoader();
          try {
               def.loadClass("my.dependency.MyClass");
               System.out.println("CLASS LOADED");
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               System.out.println("NOT LOADED");
          }
          return def;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563909/how-to-set-classpath-when-i-use-javax-tools-javacompiler-compile-the-source). You'll have to set a classpath through an options list with the `getTask()` method (as described in detail in the accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check it out. However, isn't there any way to set just the existing classLoader?

Comment: @Pavel S. - I doubt it, as it makes sense, to provide the compiler tool with a classpath that is separate from the actual application classpath. Imagine, you have one version of a class loaded but want to use another one for compiling the classes. This *requires* class separation.

Answer (score 8):

The main point is that, while a class loader loads classes, javac will call `JavaFileManager#list()` to get a listing of all the files in a package.

So to use a custom class loader you need to modify (or extend) it to override `JavaFileManager#list()`. Hopefully you can reuse some of the logic used for class loading.

You might want to use your own implementations of `JavaFileObject` to represent class objects. You will then need to override `JavaFileManager#inferBinaryName()` (else the javac version will crash). Your implementations of `JavaFileObject` also needs to override (at least) `JavaFileObject#openInputStream`.

Here are some pointers: http://atamur.blogspot.be/2009/10/using-built-in-javacompiler-with-custom.html

Also, don't make your life harder than it should and extend `ForwardingJavaFileManager` and `SimpleJavaFileObject`.

For reference, here is an example implementation:

```
  @Override public Iterable<JavaFileObject> list(Location location,
    String packageName, Set<JavaFileObject.Kind> kinds, boolean recurse)
  throws IOException
  {
    Iterable<JavaFileObject> stdResults =
      fileManager.list(location, packageName, kinds, recurse);

    if (location != StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH
    ||  !kinds.contains(JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS))
    {
        return stdResults;
    }

    Set<JavaFileObject> additional = pkgObjects.get(packageName);

    if (additional == null || additional.isEmpty()) {
      return stdResults;
    }

    List<JavaFileObject> out = new ArrayList<>();

    for (JavaFileObject obj : additional) {
      out.add(obj);
    }
    for (JavaFileObject obj : stdResults) {
      out.add(obj);
    }

    return out;
  }
```

Where `pkgObjects` is a map from package names to `JavaFileObject`. The way you fill this map depends on how your class loader works.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the class from different jar file you could try with Reflection API it is easy way ..refer the following link http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's not exactly what I need. I need to compile *.java source and let the compiler know how to load the dependency package.