# How to set the .class folder path when I use JavaCompiler to compile code?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I want to set the path in which the `.class` file generated when using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set classpath when I use javax.tools.JavaCompiler compile the source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563909/how-to-set-classpath-when-i-use-javax-tools-javacompiler-compile-the-source)

Comment: No I want to set the output location of `.class` file not classPath, already i configured ClassPath option

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("build/classes")));
```