# Compiling generated code and jar with JavaCompiler

Tags: java, code-generation, java-compiler-api

I have generated code that can be compiled on commandline with javac compiler like this:

```
javac generated/Buffer.java -classpath framework-core.jar
```

Now I am trying to automate the compiling in tests with JavaCompiler. With the following code (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html):

```
String path = "/generated/Buffer.java";
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + path);
File[] files1 = new File[]{file};
//HERE I WOULD LIKE TO GIVE framework-core.jar TO COMPILER

JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(files1));

compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();

fileManager.close();
```

I am able to produce same errors I get from the command line, if I do not provide classpath to framework-core.jar. How could I give classpath to that jar when working with programmatical JavaCompiler?

I also wonder if there would be more straightforwarded ways to compile and run generated code.

Comment: I wonder if these might helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563909/how-to-set-classpath-when-i-use-javax-tools-javacompiler-compile-the-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify `classpath` option on your java compiler:

```
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
// set compiler's classpath to the path of your framework-core.jar
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("classpath","/lib/framework-core.jar"));
...
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, optionList, null, compilationUnits1).call();
```