# javax.tools.JavaCompiler with external .class files

Tags: java

I want to compile a .java File during runtime with the javax.tools.JavaCompiler, but inside the .java file I'm using a class that's defined in an external .class files. How can i let the JavaCompiler know this class?

I tried it with the options thing from here, [How to set classpath when I use javax.tools.JavaCompiler compile the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563909/how-to-set-classpath-when-i-use-javax-tools-javacompiler-compile-the-source) , but it's not working. It could also be, that I just made something false, because the description on this link isn't huge.
Thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise regarding "it's not working". Do you have any errors?

Comment: When I try to compile it, it just says something like: "Class xyz is not defined.". This Class is defined in the .class file and now I need to let the compiler somehow know the class.