# How to use Java Compile API to compile recursively?

Tags: java, compilation, java-compiler-api

I am learing Java Compiler API recently and I write some code that can compile one simple java source code file into a class file, but it can't compile a source code file which refer another class in other source code file. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        Path path = Paths.get("demo/Test2.java");
        File sourceFile = path.toFile();
        // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", classpath));
        optionList = Arrays.asList("-d", "demo_class");
        try (StandardJavaFileManager fileManager =
                compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {
            Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects =
                    fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(sourceFile);
            JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task =
                    compiler.getTask(null, null, null, options, null, fileObjects);
            Boolean result = task.call();
            if (result == null || !result.booleanValue()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Compilation failed. class file path:" + sourceFile.getPath());
            }
        }
    }
```

demo/Test.java:

```
public class Test1 {}
```

demo/Test2.java:

```
public class Test2 extends Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test2 compiled.");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
demo/Test2.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
public class Test2 extends Test1{
                           ^
  symbol: class Test1
1 error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed. class file path:demo/Test2.java
    at test.DynamicCompile.main(DynamicCompile.java:28)
```

My question is how to make the compiler know class `Test1` is in file `Test1.java` and this file is in the same source code folder as `Test2.java` so that it can compile recursively?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicated question. The classpath is use for loading classes not source files. I add classpath option to the getTask method but still have the same ploblem.

Comment: So this question won't reopen again? The answers of question [How to set classpath when I use javax.tools.JavaCompiler compile the source ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563909/how-to-set-classpath-when-i-use-javax-tools-javacompiler-compile-the-source) can't solve this problem. @BlackSlash